# Datasource for RDL reports with ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdl

I have some RDL reports created with SQL Server BI Development Studio and now I need to render them using the ASP.NET Report Viewer. Even though my RDLs contain references to the SQL server and the SELECT query, it keeps saying I need to specify a datasource for the report. Is there a way to make the datasource from the RDL be used or do I have to pass a datasource to the report viewer via C# code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you verify the DataSourceReference element in your RDL? It needs the path to the reporting server.

> The DataSourceReference element can contain a full folder path (for
>   example, /SampleReports/AdventureWorks) or a relative path (for
>   example, AdventureWorks). Relative paths start in the same folder as
>   the report. The shared data source must be on the same server as the
>   report.

Verify the DataSourceID too. Take a look at the [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797180/using-a-shared-data-source-for-dynamically-generated-and-deployed-reports). It looks like it might be the same problem you are having.

If you are using an RDLC you could also set the datasource of your report manually using [ReportDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254370.aspx). "GetMyData" in the example below would implement IEnumerable or IDataSource.

```
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("MyDataName", GetMyData(startAt, endAt));
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reporting/MyReport.rdlc");

ReportParameterCollection col = new ReportParameterCollection();
ReportParameter startAtParam = new ReportParameter("StartAt", startAt.ToString("MMM, dd yyyy"));
col.Add(startAtParam);
ReportParameter endAtParam = new ReportParameter("EndAt", endAt.ToString("MMM, dd yyyy"));
col.Add(endAtParam);

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(col);
```

If you are converting an RDL to an RDLC you can [follow the steps here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Note that you need to re-create data source and query information. Also, the XML schema definition is different between 2005 and 2008.

Comment: I think I'm mixing things up here. I researched a bit more and found what I actually need is a RDLC, since I want to render the report definition using the Report Viewer without a report server involved. Still, I need to use my datasets and datasources from the RDL(C) file. Am I going the right direction?

Comment: But isn't it possible to just convert a RDL to RDLC, keeping the dataset and datasource specifications that come from the RDL and use them without having to do all that declaration? I mean, if I already have a query and a path to a SQL Server specified there on the RDL, I wouldn't like to do it all again just because I'm not rendering that report at a server anymore. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio did you make the report in? Take a look at the 'How to Convert Report Definitions' steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are using the Report Viewer in local mode:

```
viewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
```

and you use `viewer.LocalReport`. In this case you has to run query yourself and pass the result to the viewer:

```
dim tbl as new DataTable()
```

Fill the data e.g. tbl.load(datareader).

```
Dim VDS As New ReportDataSource
VDS.Name = "Your Data Source Name"
VDS.Value = tbl
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(VDS)
```

If you want to use server mode

```
viewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
```

You has to use `viewer.ServerReport`

```
viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri(ReportServerURL)
```

and probably `viewer.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials`

[Reporting Services and ReportViewer Controls in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345248.aspx)

**Edit**
**How to get queries from rdl**
Initialization:

```
Dim XRep As New XmlDocument
XRep.Load(ReportPath)
Dim xmlnsManager As New System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(XRep.NameTable)
dim DefaultNSURI as string = XRep.GetElementsByTagName("Width")(0).NamespaceURI
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("rep", DefaultNSURI)
```

Dataset Processing:

```
For Each nd As XmlNode In XRep.SelectNodes("/rep:Report/rep:DataSets/rep:DataSet", xmlnsManager)
   'DataSourceName can be used to find iformation about connection' 
   Dim DataSourceName As String = nd.SelectSingleNode("rep:Query/rep:DataSourceName", xmlnsManager).InnerText  
   Dim DSName As String = nd.Attributes("Name").Value       
   cmd.CommandText = nd.SelectSingleNode("rep:Query/rep:CommandText", xmlnsManager).InnerText
   Dim tbl As New DataTable(DSName)
   tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    'The table created here is to be passed to  LocalReport as datasource'
 Next
```

Note
To convert vb.net<->c# I use [Convert VB.NET to C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)