# How to set reportdatasource to rdlc report in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, .net-4.0

I am developing Winform Application and i am new to Reports (rdlc). I want to fetch data from database and set them as data source to my report in code. I am using Vb.net and following is my code I tried...

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection
Dim adpt As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim rs As DataTable
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn = New OleDbConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\tblentries.mdb"
    conn.Open()
    adpt = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from tblentries", conn)
    rs = New DataTable
    adpt.Fill(rs)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet("DataSetOne")
    ds.Tables.Add(rs)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("Report1", ds.Tables(0)))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

Result what I am getting is Blank Report Please Suggest me i am new to reporting and the codes i posted are referred from google. Thank you I'm Waiting.....

Comment: What code worked for you? Please post your functioning code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without having the rdlc file. I think that the problem is that the name you are giving to `ReportDataSource` does not match the name of datasource in the report.

Also check `ProcessingMode`

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
```

see also [Datasource for RDL reports with ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192620/669527)